# Chrome unable to find login window

Tags: javascript, selenium, google-chrome

I am using Java with Selenium and Chrome. I click on a link which brings up a login window as in the picture below. Selenium cannot find this window, nor does the driver say that there is an extra window.

I need to login to this but can't figure out how to access it.  I tried with Actions (the value of login is a dummy string right now, but when it works it will be real).

```
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.sendKeys(login).build().perform();
    actions.sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();
```

This does not work.  I don't see anything being sent into the box.

I would like to try with Javascript in the examples I have seen you need an object (found via id), but Selenium nor chrome inspect can find this login screen so I can't do that.  I tried javascript using html as the object but that did not work.

```
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html"));
    JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

We are not allowed to use Robot because that will not work with remote execution with Selenium.  It may work locally but we will be running on a grid.

Has anyone else run into this problem?  I believe a coworker says it uses the Windows security login, which Chrome can't access.  I am trying to avoid having to write this in Test Complete.

[image]

Chrome: 95.0.4638.54 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.
Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0)
Build id: 20181214-0600
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java version: 1.8.0_144

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally put the javascript code for the click instead of sending text, but neither worked.